# JqTree breaks on drag after nodeUpdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

I have a JqTree with update options and drag and drop which breaks when I try to drag an element after execute nodeUpdate function. I have prepared a demo site here:

[JqTree error demo](http://datatool.presenciadigital.es/familias)

The way to reproduce the problem is:

1. Double-click on the last node (VARIOS) and press "Guardar"
2. Try to drag it and insert after ELECTRÓNICA

The tree breaks and console launch this error:

```
tree.jquery.js:2179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addChildAtPosition' of null
```

Tested on latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on dev branch by the developer (Marco)